# jQuery append function giving syntax error in console.log

Tags: jquery

```
$(".trade-button").append('<div>
<button tabindex="2" class="btn google-analytics-make-trade-click-trade-page"<span id="tradeTotal"></span>
</button></div>');
```

I'am trying to `append` html, but it's giving syntax error.

Comment: are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @FredMaggiowski read the title. ;)

Comment: I read the title, I was hoping for some more informations :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you wrote the appending string in multiple lines. You can't do it like this, this is not valid JavaScript. You can write it in one line, or escape it correctly.

```js
$(".trade-button").append('<div><button tabindex="2" class="btn google-analytics-make-trade-click-trade-page">Trade For a Total of $0<span id="tradeTotal"></span></button></div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="trade-button"></div>
```

Or:

```js
$(".trade-button").append('<div>' + 
                          '<button tabindex="2" class="btn google-analytics-make-trade-click-trade-page">' + 
                          'Trade For a Total of $0' + 
                          '<span id="tradeTotal"></span>' + 
                          '</button></div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="trade-button"></div>
```